# How to use boolean indexing with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, boolean

I have a dataframe:

df =

```
   time  time   b
0   0.0  1.1  21
1   0.1  2.2  22
2   0.2  3.3  23
3   0.3  4.4  24
4   0.4  5.5  24
```

I also have a series for my units, defined as

su =

```
time     sal
time    zulu
b        m/s
```

Now, I want to set df.index equal to the "time (sal)" values.  Those values can be in any column and I will need to check.

I can do this as:

```
 df.index = df.values[:,(df.columns == 'time') & (su.values == 'sal')]
```

But, my index looks like:

```
array([[0.0],
       [0.1],
       [0.2],
       [0.3],
       [0.4]])
```

However, this is an array of arrays.  In bigger datasets, plot seems to take longer.  If I hardcode the value, I get just an array:

```
df.index = df[0,0]
array([0.0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4])
```

I can also do the following:

```
inx = ((df.columns == 'time') & (s.values == 'sal')).tolist().index(True)
```

This sets "inx" to 0 and then gets a single array

```
df.index=df.values[0,inx]
```

However, I shouldn't have to do this. Am I using pandas and boolean indexing incorrectly?

I want:

df =

```
   time  time   b
0.0   0.0  1.1  21
0.1   0.1  2.2  22
0.2   0.2  3.3  23
0.3   0.3  4.4  24
0.4   0.4  5.5  24
```

Comment: What does your expected output looklike?

Answer (score 1):

As I understood, this is what you expected. However, I renamed time names as time1 & time2, otherwise it won't let to create the dictionary with same name.

```
df = {'time1': [0.0,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4], 'time2': [1.1,2.2,3.3,4.4,5.5],'b':[21,22,23,24,24]}
su = {'time1':'sal', 'time2':'zulu', 'b':'m/s'}
indexes = df[su.keys()[su.values().index('sal')]]
df = pd.DataFrame(df, index=indexes, columns=['time1', 'time2', 'b'])
print df
```

[image: Output]

Comment: @userJohn, was this answer helpful for you?

Answer (score 0):

Your original DataFrame has the duplicate column name, it make complexity.
Try to modify the columns' name.

## Sample Code

```
unit = pd.Series(['sal', 'zulu', 'm/s'], index=['time', 'time', 'b'])

>>> df
   time  time     b
0   0.0   1.1  21.0
1   0.1   2.2  22.0
2   0.2   3.3  23.0
3   0.3   4.4  24.0
4   0.4   5.5  25.0

new_col = ['{}({})'.format(df.columns[i], unit[i]) for i in range(len(df.columns))]
>>> new_col 
['time(sal)', 'time(zulu)', 'b(m/s)']
>>> df.columns = new_col
>>> df
   time(sal)  time(zulu)  b(m/s)
0        0.0         1.1    21.0
1        0.1         2.2    22.0
2        0.2         3.3    23.0
3        0.3         4.4    24.0
4        0.4         5.5    25.0
>>> df.index = df['time(sal)'].values
>>> df
     time(sal)  time(zulu)  b(m/s)
0.0        0.0         1.1    21.0
0.1        0.1         2.2    22.0
0.2        0.2         3.3    23.0
0.3        0.3         4.4    24.0
0.4        0.4         5.5    25.0
```